# fsolve with two sets of variables

Tags: arrays, matlab

`fsolve` solves a problem specified by

```
F(x)=0
```

for `x`. In my case, `x` is a 2-dimensional array of size `m x n`. Now suppose
that in addition to `x`, there is a vector `y` that needs to be solved for
as well. What is the best way to expand the number of variables `fsolve`
solves for, given that `fsolve` only allows for a single argument?

One solution, one that I would like to avoid, is to rewrite the problem in
terms of a single vector with entries of `x` and `y` stacked as in

```
x(1) ...  x(m x n), y(1) ... y(m-1)
```

I would like to avoid this solution because the equations for the first set
of variables can be nicely defined in 2 dimensions.

Would it be possible to create a 3-dimensional array of size `m x n x 2` where the first page (the 3rd dimension in Matlab terminology) is the original `x`-matrix and the entries of `y` appear on the second page? But then, what is if `y` is only of size `m-1` so that the second page is largely empty? Would this be possible somehow?

---

EDIT
Here is a simplied version of the model with `m=n=2`. 
The equations in the first set are

```
x(1,1)*dot(k1,y)-y(1) = 0;
x(1,2)*dot(k2,y)-y(1) = 0;
x(2,1)*dot(k1,y)-y(2) = 0;
x(2,2)*dot(k2,y)-y(2) = 0;
```

where `k1` and `k2` are two vectors of parameters. 
When `m=n=2`, the second set of equations consists of a single equation of the form

```
y(1)*dot(c1,x(1,:)) + y(2)*dot(c2,x(2,:)) = 0
```

Where `c1` and `c2` are two vectors of parameters. The last entry of y, here `y(2)`, is always a parameter.

Comment: What are the two functions? If you can write the math it would greatly help volunteers who might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them into a single vector but you don't need to modify F. For example suppose you have a function F(x, y) where x and y are arbitrarily sized then something like the following should work

```
function [x, y] = fsolve2(F, x0, y0)
    % flatten x0 and y0 into a single column vector
    xy0 = [x0(:); y0(:)];

    % utility functions for recovering x and y from combined vector
    xstart = 1;
    xend = xstart + numel(x0) - 1;
    xsize = size(x0);
    getx = @(xy) reshape(xy(xstart:xend), xsize);
    ystart = xend + 1;
    yend = ystart + numel(y0) - 1;
    ysize = size(y0);
    gety = @(xy) reshape(xy(ystart:yend), ysize);

    % define G which takes xy and calls F
    G = @(xy) F(getx(xy), gety(xy));

    xy = fsolve(G, xy0);

    % unwrap xy into x and y
    x = getx(xy);
    y = gety(xy);
end
```

which could be called with

```
x, y = fsolve2(F, x0, y0);
```